# Action based on Local variable Angular2

Tags: angular

I want to know how to disable button depending on the value of local template varibale. here is my code -

```
<input type="text" #name>     
<button [disabled]='name.value' (click)='getvalue()'>Demo</button>
```

i want to disbale the button whenever the value of #name change, also how to get the value of #name in the class (component class) ?

here is plnkr for the same
http://plnkr.co/edit/3ZHS7jfQIVl2WVsK8BEb?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular doesn't run change detection because no event relevant to Angular is fired. If you bind to an event then Angular runs change detection and the binding works

Adding `(input)="null"` like

```
  <input type="text" #name (input)="null">
```

makes your example work.

[**Plunker example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/dkn5zDviS8Dm9rzRpOVo?p=preview)

Comment: actually i want to disable button if input field is empty, else button disable flase. how to get this ? btw whats the role `(input)` here ?

Comment: `(input)="button.disabled = !$event.target.value"`

Comment: but this works only when user fill the input box, not first time. i mean if input  field is untouched button is still not disabled which is wrong.

Comment: is there any way to bind button disable property to #name value?

Comment: I see what you mean. I would expect that to work but it doesn't.

Comment: I updated my answer. I run into this a few months ago already but forgot about it.

Comment: you mean `#name` value by default is not null ? and how to get value of #name in class constructor ?

Comment: "you mean #name value by default is not null?" No, I didn't say any of this. I just say that a binding to `name.value` is not updated because Angular doesn't run change detection when no event is bound. I don't see a way to get the value of `#name` in the constructor, only in `ngAfterViewInit()`

Answer (score 0):

After Searching found One Alternate,

actually this does't work because Angular change detection works only when any event fires, but here in this case local variable does't fire any event,
so to make change detection, we must add any event to the input field. we can do it either by calling any function or alternativly we can do it
by calling simply `keyup` event on input field like this -

```
<input type="text" #name (keyup)='name.value' />

<button [disabled]='!name.value' (click)='getvalue(name.value)' class="btn btn-md btn-primary">Demo</button>
```